# Mycology Laboratory, Department of Biology; Does it sounds strange?

Tags: terminology

**Mycology Laboratory, Department of Biology**

As we haven't had the fixed term in our native language, so I am trying to find the suggestion and idea from everyone here.

Comment: It sounds absolutely fine to me (as a native English speaker who’s worked at several universities in North America and Europe).

Comment: Great @PLL, I am very pleased!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your name sounds fine to me, but I'd use `Laboratory of Mycology, Department of Biology` (just because I think the two "of"s sound better and more official!) or a shorter form of that, such as `Mycology Lab` or `MycoLab`.

All the labs in my department are just referred to by the PI's last name, though, so that would work also!

Comment: thanks. After a long time of research, such things like this also make me nervous :) In fact it is a new division of our department.